# Как вывести числа строки массива до определенного числа? С++

Tags: c++

Допустим у нас есть двумерный динамический массив с размерностью 7x7. Значения элементов массива задаются рандомно. Далее мы нашли максимальное число в каждой строке и нам надо вывести на экран все числа, которые находятся перед максимальным значением каждой строки массива. Я не понимаю, как это реализовать. Надеюсь, понятно объяснил.

Код:

```
int x = 7;
int y = 7;

int **arr = new int*[x];

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    *(arr + i) = new int[y];
}

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] = rand() % 201 - 100;
    }
}

//Здесь мы находим максимальное число в каждой строке//

int nextv;
int A = -100;
int max = A - 1;

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    max = A - 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
    {
        if (max < (nextv = arr[i][j]))
        {
            max = nextv;
        }
    }
    cout << "Максимальное число в " << i << " строке = " << max << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int max_index;
for (int row = 0; row < x; row++)
{
    max_index = 0;
    for (int col = 1; col < y; col++)
    {
        if (arr[row][col] > arr[row][max_index])
            max_index = col;
    }
    for (int col = 0; col < max_index; col++)
    {
        cout << arr[row][col] << '\t';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```